# how to preserve older aws ecs taskdefinition revision when creating creating a new one using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating ecs taskDefinition using terraform.

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "tktest_terraform-td" {
  family = "nodejs-webapp"
  container_definitions = "${templatefile("${path.module}/taskdefinition/service-td.tpl", { webapp_docker_image = "${var.webapp_docker_image_name}:${var.webapp_docker_image_tag}"})}"
}
```

When ever there is a changes to the taskdefinition a new revision is created but the problem is the older revision is gets deleted.

Is it possible to create a new revision but the same time preserve the older revision?

Comment: Do you have any code that can demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @Marcin updated above with code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is long-lasting issue with task definition documented and discussed on [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/258).

So far, the **issue is open**, and the workaround reported is to manually remove current version of the task from the TF state. In your case it would be:

```
# we can still get the task definition diff at this point, which we care about
terraform plan

# remove from state so that task definition is not destroyed, and we're able to rollback in the future if needed
terraform state rm aws_ecs_task_definition.tktest_terraform-td

# diff will show a brand new task definition created, but that's ok because we got the diff in step 1
terraform apply
```

Comment: This indeed is the only way to not force terraform to make the previous task inactive, else terraform on an apply of `aws_ecs_task_definition` deregisters the existing task which makes it inactive, making rollbacks a problem.